# Opening SceneBuilder with Eclipse gives a CreateProcess error = 193

Tags: eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to create a JavaFX project in eclipse with the e(fx)clipse plugin. I am following a tutorial found [here](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/), but I am running into problems when trying to open a .fxml file with SceneBuilder. When I right click on the .fxml file and choose "Open with SceneBuilder", Eclipse gives me the following error:

```
Failed to launch SceneBuilder. The error message was: Cannot run program "C:\Users\path\SceneBuilder-8.0.0.jar": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I've verified over and over that the path is right, and I've reinstalled SceneBuilder several times. I am able to run SceneBuilder from outside of Eclipse. I feel like a .exe file is expected, but if that's the case, then I don't understand why the tutorial doesn't have any explanation of how to get a .exe file instead of an executable jar. I've seen posts that indicate that 193 errors occur when a JDK is x64 and the program giving an error is x32, but I believe everything that I've downloaded is 64bit.

What might be causing this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I needed to point to the .exe created by the installer that was located in the appdata folder.